# Approximation of the Heaviside Function whose derivative has a compact support

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am looking for a smooth approximation $H_\delta$ of the Heaviside function, which has the property that
$$
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+}H_\delta =H
$$
in the distribution sense, and
$$
H_\delta(x)=1,\;\;{\mbox{for}}\;\;x>\delta,\;\;H_\delta(x)=0,\;\;{\mbox{for}}\;\;x<\delta.
$$
Now, take the following function, which is a smooth approximation of the Dirac delta function with compact support: 
$$
f=\left.\exp\left(-\frac{\delta^2}{\delta^2-x^2}\right)\right.,\;\;{\mbox{for}}\;\;|x|<\delta,\;\; {\mbox{and zero elsewhere.}}
$$
The integral of $f$ from $-\delta$ to x divided by the integral of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$  will do the trick. My question is this: is there a simpler way to answer this question than by writing it as an unevaluated integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just responded to my own questions by looking at [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/are-there-other-kinds-of-bump-functions-than-e-frac1x2-1). The function is

$$
H_\delta=\dfrac{1}{1+{e^{{\tfrac {4 x\delta}{ x^2-\delta^2
 }}}}},\;\;{\mbox{for}}\;\;|x|<\delta.
$$