# Approximation of $\log(x)$ for very small $x$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, approximation

To avoid the $\log()$ function, I am looking for a good approximation of $\log(x)$ for *very small* $x$ (e.g. order $10^{-5}$).

I think Taylor series expansion is useless because around these small $x$, the first order derivative approachs $+\infty$.

I did try this approximation $\log_{10}(x) \approx 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ but still don't have satisfactory results.

Could anyone suggest some better approximations?

Comment: $\frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}$

Comment: Since $\log 1/x=-\log x$, an approximation for very small $x$ would be the same as an approximation for very large $x$.

Comment: @gammatester very funny.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for quick comment. However, as I said, I am trying to avoid the $\log()$ function. Can you please tell me the good approximation of $\log(x)$ for very large $x$?

Comment: This is not funny. It is an exact relation between $\log_{10}$ and $\ln$. Because $0$ is a logarithmic branch point of $\log_{10}$ other approximations make no sense (also not for large $x$).

Comment: @gammatester I am sorry if my question was not clear, but I do not seek for *at zero* approximation, but the approximation which is *good enough* at *small $x$*.

Comment: Define *good enough*

Comment: @AlexTP I don't know that there is a good approximation for very large $x$, but I am highly skeptical.  My point was that it might seem like there was one for small $x$ because you're looking in a very tiny place, but if there were that approximation, there would also be a very very unlikely approximation too.

Comment: @gammatester as I said in the question, better than $\log(x) \approx 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Please see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977657/471884.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks, I did not find this in the first search attempt. It seems my question is dupicated of that question. However, any new answer is welcomed. I will delete my question in a week if I do not receive any new answer.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire That is an approximation for $\log x$ if you already know $\lfloor \log x/\log 10 \rfloor$.  I don't know if that would be considered cheating or not (as you can count the number of digits if you are given your number as a decimal, but you have a problem of equivalent difficulty to find the number of digits if you aren't presented the number in that form).  I don't know the application, so I can't really say if that is a realistic assumption in the use case.

Comment: Perhaps you should say **why** you would use an approximation. There are very few functions which are simpler than $\ln$. This should avoid a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @gammatester I am trying to transform an equation to polynominal form. However, I do have another problem that I should keep the $\log$ function and approximate another function. I will ask it in a seperate post and link to this question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln x\sim\frac{1-x^{-x}}x\qquad{(x\to 0)}$$

or

$$\ln x\sim \frac{x^x-1}x$$

---

Since $x^x\approx 1$ for small $x$,

$$\ln x=\frac1x\ln x^x=\frac1x\ln(1+(x^x-1))\sim\frac{x^x-1}x$$

Comment: Is the power of a floating point also not slow to evaluate? I tried [here](https://gist.github.com/boennecd/2bbaad7a6387eebaefe4487167b903e5) and using your approximation with `std::pow` with gcc `8.4.0` took twice as long as using `std::log` in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to allow square roots, then the sequence of functions
$\, f_n(x) := 2^n(\sqrt[2^n]{x}-1)\,$ give better and better results. 
In fact, $\, f_n(x) \to \ln(x)\,$ as $\, n \to \infty\,$ for all $\,x>0.\,$
Once you have $\,\ln(x)\,$ you can use
 $\, \log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}.$

Comment: just stating that $$\ln(x)\approx x(x^\frac{1}{x}-1)$$ works for big $x$, at least on Wolfram-Alpha

Answer (score 1):

Working in this [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838311/909869) I found that one could use this approximation:
$$\ln(x) \approx \frac{\left(x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-1\right)}{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}}\ln(x+1)$$

From this you could use the Taylor's expansion of $\ln(x+1)$ at $x=0$. But from the plot looks it works only for $x>0.4$ and I don't think it going to match the exact values as the order increases (with the exact functions [it fails](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%28x%29%2C+%28x%5E%281%2Fln%282%29%29-1%29%2Fx%5E%281%2Fln%282%29%29*ln%281%2Bx%29%2C+from+x%3D0+to+1)), but at least works better than the Taylor's expansion of $\ln(x)$ at $x=1$ near $x=0$.

([see the plot here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%28x%29%2C+%28x%5E%281%2Fln%282%29%29-1%29%2F%28x%5E%281%2Fln%282%29%29%29*%28x-x%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E3%2F3-x%5E4%2F4%2Bx%5E5%2F5-x%5E6%2F6%2Bx%5E7%2F7-x%5E8%2F8%2Bx%5E9%2F9-x%5E10%2F10%29%2C+from+x%3D0+to+2)).

[image: Taylor expansion approximation]

Comment: Yeah, even though it does not work for small $x$, it's nice to know this approximation.