# What are the steps you would use to calculate $\log_{e}3$ using a Finite Differences Method?

Tags: logarithms, power-series, finite-differences

We know that [Babbage's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) [Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) could calculate the sum of polynomials. This was important to him because of his [work on logarithms](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=piNNAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). This relies on the sum of finite differences.

We know that we can manually calculate a logarithm [using a power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm).

So a logarithm can be calculated as:
[image]

I'm trying to draw up the table of polynomial results for $\log_{e}3$ that I'd expect the Difference Engine to output.

We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine#Method_of_differences) that the Difference Engine tabulated polynomials using a [Finite Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method) Method.

My question is: **What are the steps you would use to calculate $\log_{e}3$  using a Finite Differences Method?**

Comment: A minor point, but I think Polynomials are finite. However, a Series could be either infinite as in the case of log or finite.

Comment: It is easy to assume that one would assume n terms of the series to be accurate enough and end with a Polynomial where one could use interpolation/extrapolation with, but this is a general  guess. Maybe this helps: http://ed-thelen.org/bab/bab-intro.html

Comment: Thanks @NoChance that’s helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logarithms and the history from Babbage's time are truly fascinating.

So we start with [the Binomial Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/977586/109927) noting this is only useful between 0 and 1:

$$ \ln x = (x-1) - \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + ....$$

We'll do this for a sixth order polynomial:

$$ \ln x = (x-1) - \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(x-1)^3  + \frac{1}{4}(x-1)^4  + \frac{1}{5}(x-1)^5  + \frac{1}{6}(x-1)^6 $$

As an excel function - this looks like this:

```
=(C161-1)-(1/2)*POWER((C161-1),2)+(1/3)*POWER((C161-1),3)-(1/4)*POWER((C161-1),4)+(1/5)*POWER((C161-1),5)-(1/6)*POWER((C161-1),6)
```

To understand sum of the differences we look at the following example:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x& p(x) = 2x^2 − 3x + 2 & diff1(x) = ( p(x + 1) − p(x) ) & diff2(x) = ( diff1(x + 1) − diff1(x) ) \\ \hline
0 & 2& -1&4\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 3 &4\\ \hline
2 & 4 & 7&4\\ \hline
3 & 11 & 11 &\\ \hline
4 & 22 & &\\ \hline
\end{array}

ie you keep adding the number in the right column to the next column over, and each row you carry the sum over to the right. (You can see a detailed video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFMBU17eo_4&feature=youtu.be)).

Now we build a table for this polynomial of sum of the differences between 0 and 1:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
index & binomial calculation & 1st  diff & 2nd diff & 3rd diff & 4th diff & 5th diff & 6th diff \\ \hline
1&0.00000&&&&&&\\ \hline
0.9&-0.10536&-0.10536&&&&&\\ \hline
0.8&-0.22314&-0.11778&-0.01242&&&&\\ \hline
0.7&-0.35663&-0.13349&-0.01571&-0.00329&&&\\ \hline
0.6&-0.51046&-0.15383&-0.02034&-0.00463&-0.00134&&\\ \hline
0.5&-0.69115&-0.18068&-0.02685&-0.00651&-0.00188&-0.00054&\\ \hline
0.4&-0.90773&-0.21658&-0.03590&-0.00905&-0.00254&-0.00066&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.3&-1.17258&-0.26485&-0.04827&-0.01237&-0.00332&-0.00078&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.2&-1.50229&-0.32971&-0.06486&-0.01659&-0.00422&-0.00090&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.1&-1.91870&-0.41640&-0.08669&-0.02183&-0.00524&-0.00102&-0.00012\\ \hline
\end{array}

Now we shuffle top of columns to top row

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
index & binomial calculation & 1st  diff & 2nd diff & 3rd diff & 4th diff & 5th diff & 6th diff \\ \hline
1&0.00000&-0.10536&-0.01242&-0.00329&-0.00134&-0.00054&-0.00012\\ \hline
\end{array}

Then we fill in first row with precomputed values, then fill down by adding the number above and above right

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
index & binomial calculation & 1st  diff & 2nd diff & 3rd diff & 4th diff & 5th diff & 6th diff \\ \hline
1&0.00000&-0.10536&-0.01242&-0.00329&-0.00134&-0.00054&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.9&-0.10536&-0.11778&-0.01571&-0.00463&-0.00188&-0.00066&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.8&-0.22314&-0.13349&-0.02034&-0.00651&-0.00254&-0.00078&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.7&-0.35663&-0.15383&-0.02685&-0.00905&-0.00332&-0.00090&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.6&-0.51046&-0.18068&-0.03590&-0.01237&-0.00422&-0.00102&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.5&-0.69115&-0.21658&-0.04827&-0.01659&-0.00524&-0.00114&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.4&-0.90773&-0.26485&-0.06486&-0.02183&-0.00638&-0.00126&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.3&-1.17258&-0.32971&-0.08669&-0.02821&-0.00764&-0.00138&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.2&-1.50229&-0.41640&-0.11490&-0.03585&-0.00902&-0.00150&-0.00012\\ \hline
0.1&-1.91870&-0.53130&-0.15075&-0.04487&-0.01052&-0.00162&-0.00012\\ \hline
\end{array}

Now we have a value for ln 0.3 = -1.1725805

Now to convert ln 0.3 to ln 3 we add   ln 10 which is approx 2.302

And we get ln 3 = 1.1294195 which is close to a computed value of ln 3 = 1.098612289