# Is it true that $\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} 2^n\cdot (x^{1/2^n}-1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was going through and old book and I came across with a discussion which culminated with something like

\begin{align*}
\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} 2^n\cdot (x^{1/2^n}-1) 
\end{align*}
for every $x>0$. Is it really true? If that is the case, how to prove it?

I tried to test some values using using Geogebra and Google Sheets and both expressions produced really close values for small $n$ but it became impractible to analyse the behaviour of $2^n\cdot (x^{1/2^n}-1)$ as $n$ goes to infity for $2^n$ grows too fast.

Thanks.

Comment: You can identify $2^{-n}$ as $h$ and then arrive at something that is probably more familiar to you.

Comment: Yep, that's right! Now I get the point. The author wants to define $ln(x)$ using the above expression, that is not the case that he tries to show it. He then proceeds to show all the usual properties of $\ln$. He then uses this to define $e$, $e^x$ and $a^x$. That is an interesting approach.

Comment: This has been asked a few times already, e.g. at [Logarithm approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976048/logarithm-approximation).

Answer (score 2):

We can let $t=1/2^n$, and our limit becomes $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\left(x^{1/2^n}-1\right)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\left(x^t-1\right).$$
Then, we can rewrite this as $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{x^t-1}t=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{x^t-x^0}{t-0}=\left.\left.\frac{d}{dt}x^t\right|_{t=0}=\log x\cdot x^t\right|_{t=0}=\log x$$ as desired.

Comment: ...unless for some reason the derivative of the exponential function has not yet been learned.

Comment: It should be $t \to 0^+$ instead of $t \to 0$.

Comment: @jjagmath Does this then invalidate the whole thing as I've only found a one-sided limit?  I've found the one-sided derivative?

Comment: No. You actually found the (two-sided) limit $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{x^t-1}t = \log x$ which implies the one-sided limit $\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{x^t-1}t $ is also equal to $\log x$. Just need to be careful because that won't always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n(x^{2^{-n}}-1) = \ln x.$$

HINT: Replace $2^n=Y$. Then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n(x^{2^{-n}}-1) \ = \ \lim_{Y \rightarrow \infty} Y(x^{\frac{1}{Y}}-1).$$

Then $$\lim_{Y \rightarrow \infty} Y(x^{\frac{1}{Y}}-1) = \lim_{Y \rightarrow \infty} Y \times (e^{\frac{\ln x}{Y}}-1)$$
$$=\lim_{Y \rightarrow \infty} Y \times \left(\frac{\ln x}{Y} - O\left(\frac{\ln X}{Y}\right)^2\right) \ = \ \lim_{Y \rightarrow \infty} \ln x - O\left(\frac{\ln^2 X}{Y}\right)$$
$$= \ln x.$$

The third to last equation due to the Taylor expansion of $\ln y$ for $y$ close to $1$.