# What is a good approximation for $a-\log_{10}\left(10^a-1\right)$?

Tags: logarithms, approximation

I’m trying to find a good approximation for $a-\log_{10}\left(10^a-1\right)$, with $a$ being a large positive real number.

I think the result should be in the order of magnitude of $10^{-a}$, but I can’t find a way to prove whether or not this is the case.

Comment: You could use $\ln(1-x)\approx -x$ for small $x$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977586/is-there-an-approximation-to-the-natural-log-function-at-large-values

Comment: $f(x)-f(x-1)=f'(c)$, for $x-1<c<x$, and $f(t)=log_{10} x$, $f'(t)={1\over t .\ln(10)}$. For $x=10^a$, we get your result is approximately ${1\over 10^a .\ln(10)}$

Comment: @Thomas, thank you, that should do, do you happen to have any source for it?