# Bump function derivative control

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a smooth bump function $\Phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that the sequence $M_k = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\Phi^{(k)}(x)|$ does not grow faster than exponentially? In general, are there examples of $\Phi$ where the $M_k$ grow (much) slower than in the case of $e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$ (or the like)?

By smooth bump function, I mean a $C^\infty$ function that is $1$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ with compact support.

Pointers to other resources on this are appreciated as well.

Comment: Please take a look on that answer by Robert Israel: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/are-there-other-kinds-of-bump-functions-than-e-frac1x2-1#101484

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is marking this as a duplicate. I'm not just asking for other bump functions, I'm asking for a bump function who's derivatives don't grow too fast, as made precisely in the original question statement.

Comment: @guest123 Almost 6y late, but try to build your bump function as in the standard case but consider $f(x)\times e^{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$ instead of $ e^{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$. Play with $f$ to controll the growth / the derivative

Comment: A bit late too, but the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349280/bump-functions-whose-derivatives-fnx-converge-to-0-uniformly-as-n-to/4349292#4349292) shows that the function you are looking for doesn´t exist