# Is there a smooth function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)=\frac1x$ for all $x\ge1$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

Is there a smooth (infinitely times continuously differentiable) function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)=\frac1x$ for all $x\ge1$? Intuitively, it should be possible to construct such a function.

Comment: Is your function not an example of a smooth function?

Comment: @JacobJones The OP wants a smooth function over $\mathbb{R}$ that *extends* $1/x$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem#Extension_in_a_half_space

Comment: Note that such a function cannot be analytic.  So any example will be a $C^\infty$ but not analytic function, typically constructed using the example $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ as a starting point.  This function is nice and smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ but runs into trouble near the origin in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the smooth function
$$
f(x)=\cases{e^{-1/x^2}& if $x>0$\\0& otherwise}
$$
Now consider the function $f(x-0.5)f(1-x)$. It is smooth, on $(0.5,1)$ it is strictly positive, and it is $0$ everywhere outside $(0.5,1)$.

Now define
$$
g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t-0.5)f(1-t)dt
$$
It is smooth, it is constantly $0$ on $(-\infty, 0.5)$, and it is constantly equal to $g(1)>0$ on $(1,\infty)$.

Now $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(1)x}$ is is the function you're after (with the specification that $h(0)=0$).

---

It is more common to see this done with $f(x)f(1-x)$. I chose not to do this in order to entirely avoid any discussion about whether the limiting behaviour of $\frac1x$ as $x\to0$ interferes.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/are-there-other-kinds-of-bump-functions-than-e-frac1x2-1/2064866#2064866) to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/are-there-other-kinds-of-bump-functions-than-e-frac1x2-1) gives the construction of a $C^\infty$ bump function, which can also be found in many analysis textbooks. If you read and understand it, you can most likely see how to generalize that construction to produce the function you desire, as well as many other similar functions.