# Function similar to sigmoid but whose range is $[0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I would like to map $\mathbb{R}$ onto $[0, 1)$. Is there a function similar to the sigmoid (shapewise) that is continuous and has range onto $[0, 1)$? Unfortunately the sigmoid doesn't include the $0$ i.e. $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\to(0, 1)$

Comment: There is are surjective continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ onto $[0,1)$ and there are also  bijective functions, but not a bijective continuous function.  The problem is that all real numbers have neighbourhoods going above and below, but $0$ do not have a neighbourhood going below in $[0,1)$

Comment: So for example $f(x) =1-e^{-x^2}$ is a surjective continuous function from $\mathbb R$ onto $[0,1)$ with $f(0)=0$ but $f(1)=f(-1) \approx 0.6321$ shows this is not bijective

Comment: You might be interested in the [smoothstep functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101480/81360).