# A $C^1$ function that vanishes in both directions

Tags: functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I am seeking for a $C^1$ function s.t. $f(x)=0$ iff $x\in(-\infty,x_1]\cup[x_2,\infty)$. I can imagine that $f$ is something like this:

[image]

Do you know about some function like this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried writing a piecewise formula, and if so, what seems not to be working?

Comment: One would be $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\le x_1\lor x\ge x_2\\ \exp\frac1{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}&\text{if }x_1<x<x_2\end{cases}$, which is also $C^\infty$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101480/are-there-other-kinds-of-bump-functions-than-e-frac1x2-1

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio perfect! Thank you really much.

Comment: @JackT, great question, thank you!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I was with trouble to mantain the property $C^1$ because I did not know about bumps. Thank yoU!

Comment: If it matters, to ensure $C^1$ it's enough to ensure the "bump" has derivative $0$ at the endpoints $x_1$ and $x_2$, e.g., $f(x) = (x - x_1)^2(x - x_2)^2$ on $[x_1,x_2]$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you!