# A smooth version of the $\log$ function

Tags: analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, smooth-functions

How to construct a smooth modification of the $\log$ function? We want to construct a  concrete function $\log^\varepsilon x$ with the following characteristics:

1. $\log^\varepsilon(x)$ is smooth function in $[0,+\infty)$
2. $\log^\varepsilon(x)=\log x, \forall x\ge \varepsilon$
3. $|(\log^\varepsilon(x))'|\le C\cdot 1/x , \forall x\ge 0 $
   where $C$ is not depend on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: On the interval $(0, \epsilon)$ you can define a polynomial of some degree, say $k$. You then choose the coefficients such that the there is a smooth connection between the polynomial and $log(x)$ at $x = \epsilon$.

Comment: @M. Wind We need to take C not depend on $\varepsilon$, if we choose polynomial， the coefficents will depend on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Gonçalo $C^\infty$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using a cut-off function.

[image]

where $p_\epsilon$ is a smooth cut-off function and $(p_\epsilon)'\le \frac{C}{\epsilon}$, $q_\epsilon:=1-p_\epsilon$.

Define $\log^\epsilon(x):=q_\epsilon(x)\log(\epsilon )+p_\epsilon(x)\log(x)$, then $\log^\epsilon(x)$ is a smooth function, $\log(x)=\log^\epsilon(x),\forall x\ge\epsilon$ and
\begin{align*}
 (\log^\epsilon(x))'=&p_\epsilon(x)\frac{1}{x}+\log(\epsilon) q_\epsilon'(x)+p_\epsilon'(x)\log(x)\\
\le& C\frac{1}{x}+(\log(x)-\log(\epsilon))p_\epsilon'(x)\\
\le& C\frac{1}{x}+C|\log(x/\epsilon)|\frac{1}{\epsilon}.
\end{align*}
We just need to consider the case $\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le x\le \epsilon$, in that case $|\log(x/\epsilon)|\frac{1}{\epsilon}\le C\frac{1}{x}$. So we obtain $$(\log^\epsilon(x))'\le C\frac{1}{x}, \forall x\ge 0,$$
where $C$ is not depend on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a [smooth transition function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions) you could built what you want.

As example think of
$$q(x)=\dfrac{2}{1+\exp\left({\dfrac{1}{16x^2}}\right)}$$
which is a [flat function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) near zero, this will make the trick.

Now let $f(x)$ be your objective functiom $$f(x)=\log(x)$$

then an smooth approximation will be:
$$r(x)=f(x)\cdot q(x)\equiv \dfrac{2\log(x)}{1+\exp\left({\dfrac{1}{16x^2}}\right)}$$

which you could see in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yliyzqcv1o):

[image: example]

Comment: Using Kernel Smoothing may got it, thank you.

Comment: @Measure32 Please consider accepting the answer if it fulfill your expectations.

Comment: I don't understand how this function satisfies the second criterion.

Comment: @M.Wind it work only as approximation (since the kernel goes to one), but you could do use other smooth transition functions with a steper increase (more elaborated ones). As example, make the smooth bump function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,\ x=0, \\ 0,\ |x|\geq 1, \\ \dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}\end{cases}$$ then make the smooth transition function $$t(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^x f(y)\ dy$$ so you can now make a kernel $$q(x)=t(ax-1)$$ with $a>1$ managing how fast it rises to the value $1$ (so $a$ is related to $\epsilon$), so now $$r(t)=q(x)\log(x)$$ fulfill point 2

Comment: @M.Wind you could check it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z2vqvjrgc7), but it takes a lot to load the graphs

Comment: @M.Wind here in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wodv3boics) you could see another slightly simpler example using the classic [bump function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function): $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,\ |x|\geq 1,\\ e^{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}},\ |x|<1\end{cases}$$ There are plenty of these functions, [look them here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101480/909869)

Comment: @Joako $r(t)$ be similarly  not  in $C^\infty$

Comment: @Measure32 How not? it will be $C^{\infty}(0,\ +\infty)$ as required: those smooth transition functions goes to zero at $x=0$ in a "much stronger" way that the divergence of any logarythm

Comment: @Joako I just see the Desmos, I need to check it!

Comment: @Measure32 the relation among $a$ and $\epsilon$ is given just how you manage the scaling and translations of the argument of $q(x)$... I am pretty sure that part could be solved by you since you already know what is a smooth function.

Comment: @Measure32 even you could avoid using the integral kind of transition function by properly defining piecewise just a half of a bump function with the right-side-half fixed at $1$ forever after, and then translating and scaling it (example [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nkrpivwdsg), run faster on Desmos)

Comment: @Joako  Characteristics 3.  be similarly hard to satisfied since $(q^\epsilon)'\le  C\cdot 1/\epsilon$

Comment: @Measure32 That is a different requirement that $(q^\epsilon \log(x))'\leq \frac{C}{x},\ \forall x>\epsilon$

Comment: @Measure32 even tho [last example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s1nvmawurp) fulfill $|(q^\epsilon(x) \log(x))'|\leq \frac{1}{x},\ \forall \epsilon>0$ which satisfies condition (3) for $C=1$

Comment: @Measure32 I have realized my last statement is wrong, it don't work for every possible positive $\epsilon$, I tried among $\epsilon\in[0.5,\ 10]$ and it works, but for smaller or bigger epsilon indeed could happen its higher than $1/x$. It left to be proved if exist a higher constant $C$ independent from $\epsilon$ that could do the trick.